# Kivy App crashes when using anything that needs internet

Tags: python, android, kivy, buildozer, kivymd

i am new to kivy and would like some help guys .

i am building a Kivy App with buildozer for android , that uses an outsource API from cryptocompare.com

it is a very simple app that shows the Cryptocurrency prices , live updated.

the app crashes instantly when opened ..
i removed the API and created a Dict instead, just to test if the App will work or not , and the app runs perfectly on android .. when i put back the API , it just keep crashing .
note that the app works fine on Pycharm with no error .. also the Buildozer gives no error ..
i've been trying to find out the problem for so long .
tried every possible way . no luck.

almost included everything in android.permissions with no luck also .

this is my app code

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.screen import Screen
from kivymd.uix.list import MDList, TwoLineListItem
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.network.urlrequest import UrlRequest


class CryptoPrices(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        screen = Screen()
        scroll = ScrollView()
        listview = MDList()
        scroll.add_widget(listview)

        def got_json(req, result):
            for x, y in result.items():
                name = x
                symbol = str(y["USD"]) + " USD"
                item1 = TwoLineListItem(text=name, secondary_text=str(symbol))
                listview.add_widget(item1)

        req = UrlRequest('https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=BTC,BCH,LTC,XLM,DASH,XEM,LIBRA,BNB,ETH,XMR,XRP,LTC&tsyms=USD', got_json)

        screen.add_widget(scroll)
        return screen


if __name__ == '__main__':
    CryptoPrices().run()
```

link to buildozer.specs
https://textuploader.com/1f7ie

link to log file
https://textuploader.com/1f7ii

Answer (score 0):

Two possible issues:

1. You may need to request runtime permissions. See [runtime permissions](https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/apis/#runtime-permissions)
2. You might need to add `requests` to your requirements in the spec file.

Comment: added requests to requirements
added runtime permissions
no error in buildozer logs but still the app crashes on android.

Answer (score 0):

From the buildozer.spec file, you have to set internet permissions.
By default this option is commented, just uncomment it and the app should work fine.

Answer (score -1):

The logfile that you have added is buildozer log when the app is being built. To get the app log  when it's running, add the logcat function (`buildozer android logcat`) In app logs you can find what causing your app to crash any requirements or permission or anything else